# How do I detect duplicate strings in android?

Tags: android, string

My code saves a string from edit text every time I press a button. But If I type the same string again, It would save it regardless. How do I prevent it from saving if it has been saved before already?

```
HistoryHelper file = new HistoryHelper(getBaseContext());
                // get date
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int date = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
                int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;// fixes wrong month
                int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                file.writeToSD("Date: " + year + "-" + month + "-" + date);
                // get string
                file.writeToSD(NEWLINK.toString());
                // leave a blank line space
                file.writeToSD("".toString());
```

Comment: add all the saved strings into a list and use contains method to check if it already exists then just ignore it

Comment: where is the code that is getting the input from the edit text?

Comment: Your answer is like, "if you are thirsty, drink water". but where is the water?

Comment: Please post a complete code example that illustrates what you have tried so far.

Comment: saves it where? if it is in some local db, then check your cache. only add it if it is not there